# No SMS Spoofing attack vector in Kali Linux!

Tags: kali-linux, spoofing

I just realized that there is no SMS spoofing attack vector included in the latest version of Kali Linux. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3):

They took it out. You will need to find an old version of the SET kit or an older version of KALI. However the SMS spoofing will fail unless you can find a SMS gateway to use and most will cost money.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only about a tool in Kali then you can always use  Set  [ToolKit](http://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/set). For more information on how to use it, you can check [this](http://mile2.com/latest-news/sms-spoofing-with-new-kali-linux.html) or [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGim5NKw4KI).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest finding an SMS messaging API that allows you to change the Sender ID.  Some of the more popular, well-known SMS messaging APIs such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app) do not allow you to change the Sender ID to a random value, for it has to be a valid phone number that you have bought through the Twilio API service.  When you do find an API service that allows customers to choose the Sender ID, check out their terms of service just to check if spoofing the sender ID is a breach of contract or not.

As others suggest, you could use [SEToolkit](https://www.trustedsec.com/social-engineer-toolkit), however, I am not sure if the most recent version supports the SMS spoofing attack vector.  Regardless, you will still need an SMS gateway, so I would suggest finding an SMS messaging API that allows you to change the Sender ID which will probably be quite hard.